# lock desktop without a super key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I've a really old but beloved keyboard that lacks any super/windows/apple/whatever key.  Is there any way I can lock my desktop without picking "suspend" from the upper right menu with my mouse?  (Super-L does work when I plug in a newer keyboard as a test.)  I've tried various combinations of Shift-Ctrl-Alt without luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the default shortcut editing the dconf. For example, to set it to Ctrl+Alt+L you can type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver "<Ctrl><Alt>l"
```